# Создание очереди из структур

Tags: c++

Есть у меня база данных, я считал с этой базы данные, занес их в Persone(500 раз) и теперь мне надо поместить их в очередь, но что-то у меня не получается поместить в очередь все 500 структур Persone, а только одну, как сделать нормальную очередь из структур?

```
struct Persone
{
    char fullname[32];
    int num;
    char date[10];
};

struct spis
{
    struct spis *next;
    struct Persone *data;
};

struct queue //очереди для digital sort
{
    struct spis *head;
    struct spis *tail;
}Q;


void add(struct spis *&head,struct spis *&tail,struct Persone *array){
     struct spis *p=(struct spis*)malloc(sizeof(struct spis));
    p->data = array;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = p;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
    }
}

int main()
{
struct spis *p;
struct spis *BaseHead;
struct spis *BaseTail;
BaseHead =(struct spis*)malloc(sizeof(struct spis));
BaseTail =(struct spis*)malloc(sizeof(struct spis));
BaseHead=NULL; BaseTail=NULL;

struct Vertex *root = NULL;

struct  Persone note[4000];

    FILE *fp; // Считываем данные из бд
    fp = fopen("basa.txt", "r");
    fread(&note, sizeof(struct Persone), 500, fp);
    fclose(fp);

add(BaseHead,BaseTail,note);
printf("%s",BaseHead->data->fullname);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: так вы только один раз вызываете add и добавляете все элементы note в первый узел очереди в виде data

Comment: `printf("%s",BaseHead->data->fullname);` на самом деле `printf("%s",BaseHead->(*(data+0))->fullname);`, для вывода второго надо `printf("%s",BaseHead->(*(data+1))->fullname);`

Comment: А ваш компилятор не C++, что вы каждый раз повторяете  слово  " struct " ? По одному  (FILE *) уже можно понять что  пишете на C++...

Comment: @Komdosh не получается у меня цикл сделать

Comment: так добавьте в вопрос, как вы пытались сделать с циклом

Comment: @Komdosh единственная моя идея, это for(int i=0;i<500;i++) {add(BaseHead,BaseTail,note);} но тут надо как-то сделать что бы в сдвиг делался в add

Comment: таким образом вы добавите 500 узлов с одним и тем же массивом note

Comment: @Komdosh ну щас методом перебор всех моих глупых идей( к note добавить следующий элемент) у меня получилось заполнить, кажется, вместо note сделал note+i. Теперь есть еще вопрос, как зациклить вывод?

Comment: @Komdosh я правда не понимаю почему это вообще работает `for(int i=0;i<500;i++) add(BaseHead,BaseTail,note+i);`

Comment: `struct spis *t; t=BaseHead;` и в цикле `while(t!=null){t=t->next;}`

Comment: лучше note[i] писать, note+i не совсем верный вариант

Comment: @Komdosh в том - то и суть,  я все что знаю перепробовал через note[i], не работает, щас поставил, тоже не работает, а через note+i работает. `cannot convert 'Persone' to 'Persone*' for argument '3' to 'void add(spis*&, spis*&, Persone*)` вот что пишет, я пробовал добавлять в функции add [] в эррей, но не работало что-то постоянно

Comment: правильно, потому что note[i] это не указатель на Person, а сам Person

Comment: @Komdosh то есть надо писать не Persone* note, а Persone note[]?

Comment: это тоже самое, нет, эта переписка уже давно должна была вас навести на мысль, что у вас недостаточно теоретических знаний и надо пойти почитать про указатели